# Hangs up while booting after editing grub.cfg

Tags: 10.04, boot, rsyslog

My Lucid install won't boot properly anymore. I can boot the computer with a USB-stick-ubuntu and edit settings. I have edited grub.cfg to not boot "quiet splash" and changed the default runlevel to 1.

When continuing to boot from the recovery menu, I get this line:

`init: rsyslog main process ended, respawning.`

I did a aptitude reinstall rsyslog, which changed nothing. Does someone have an idea where to continue searching for the cause?

Thanks in advance,

Comment: The problem probably has to do with your rsyslog configuration (either there's something wrong there or there's something wrong in the places where you're sending logs). Post the contents of your configuration files (`/etc/rsyslog.conf`, `/etc/default/rsyslog`, `/etc/init/rsyslog.conf`, any file in the `rsyslog` package that you've changed).

Answer (score 1):

The primary configuration file for changing menu display settings is `/etc/default/grub`.
Configuration changes are normally made to `/etc/default/grub` and to the custom files located in `/etc/grub.d`.

**The /boot/grub/grub.cfg file should not be edited by the user**; changes to this file are made by configuration scripts.

*grub.cfg* is overwritten anytime there is an update, a kernel is added/removed, or the user runs update-grub. After editing `/etc/default/grub`, you need to run `sudo update-grub` for your changes to take effect on the next boot.

The user can use a custom file, `/etc/grub.d/40_custom`, in which the user can place his own entries. This file will not be overwritten.